# Given two angles of elevation, find height

Tags: trigonometry, angle

From a ship at sea, the angle of elevation of the top and bottom of a vertical lighthouse standing on the edge of a vertical cliff are $33^{\circ}$ and $28^{\circ}$, respectively. If the lighthouse is $20$ units  high, calculate the height of the cliff.

Here's the diagram I came up with. I am not sure what to do next.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Have you tried drawing a picture?

Answer (score 1):

In $\Delta SQR$,
$$\tan 28°=\frac{QR}{SR}\Rightarrow SR=\frac{QR}{\tan 28°}$$
and in $\Delta SPR$,
$$\tan 33°=\frac{PR}{SR}\Rightarrow SR=\frac{PR}{\tan 33°}.$$
$\therefore QR\tan 33°=PR\tan 28°\\
\Rightarrow QR\tan 33°=(PQ+QR)\tan 28°\\
\Rightarrow QR~(\tan 33°-\tan 28°)=20\tan 28°$

 Now, using $\tan 28°=0.532$ and $\tan 33°=0.649$, we get
$$QR=\frac{20\times0.532}{0.649-0.532}=90.940\mathrm{~~~units.}$$
The cliff is of height $90.940$ units.